# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Well, I see that here are a few posts like this, but they didn't help me ...

let me describe my problem:

I have two Schema's

```
var A = new Schema({
   someAttribut: {type: String},
   b: {type: ObjectId, ref:'B'}
});

var B = new Schema({
   someAttribut2: {type: Boolean, 'default': false'}
});
```

Now I'm in the situation that I already have a B-Object and I want to create an A-Object.

So i do it this way:

```
var a = new A(req.aFromClient); // {_id:null, someAttribute:'123', b:null}
//load b from Database ... 
a.b = existingBFromDatabase; // {_id: 'Sb~Õ5ÙÐDâb', someAttribute2: false}
```

*The b object is loaded from my monogDB. The debugger shows me a valid ObjectId (53627ed535d9d04416e26218 or Sb~Õ5ÙÐDâb) for my b .*

But when I save my new A-Object, i get the error: **'CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id"'**

I don't understand why I get this error. 
Firstly, I don't define the id in the schema, so mongoose should add it, which seems to work. 
Secondly, I think that mongoose should generate a new ID when I create an a object.

do you have any proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment in the code, `_id` *does* have a value (of `null`).  So you need to remove `_id` from `req.aFromClient` before creating your new `A` doc from it:

```
delete req.aFromClient._id;
var a = new A(req.aFromClient);
```

Comment: Would it be enough to set it to undefined ?

Comment: @Laokoon No, if you want Mongoose to provide an `_id` value for your new doc, you can't include an `_id` property in your initial doc object.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
a.b = existingBFromDatabase._id;
```

Because mongoose only works with the id of the already existing object.