# Skip or Disable validation for mongoose model save() call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I'm looking to create a new Document that is saved to the MongoDB regardless of if it is valid. I just want to temporarily skip mongoose validation upon the model save call.

In my case of CSV import, some required fields are not included in the CSV file, especially the reference fields to the other document. Then, the mongoose validation required check is not passed for the following example:

```
var product = mongoose.model("Product", Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
    supplier: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Supplier",
        required: true,
        default: {}
    }
}));

var data = {
    name: 'Test',
    price: 99
}; // this may be array of documents either

product(data).save(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Is it possible to let Mongoose know to not execute validation in the `save()` call?

#### [Edit]

I alternatively tried [Model.create()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create), but it invokes the validation process too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though there may be a way to disable validation that I am not aware of one of your options is to use methods that do not use middleware (and hence no validation). One of these is [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/) which accesses the Mongo driver directly.

```
Product.collection.insert({
  item: "ABC1",
  details: {
    model: "14Q3",
    manufacturer: "XYZ Company"
  },

}, function(err, doc) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(doc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have no `conditions` to `findOneAndUpdate`. It will be just pure insert. What about other methods?

Comment: @Sithu - I have added an example using `insert` which is another one of the driver methods.

Comment: It seems working and upvoted, but I got the error [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444670/casterror-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-at-path-id). According to my updated example, the error seems pointing to the `supplier` field although I have a default value. Sorry, I'm new to mongodb and mongoose.

Comment: Humm...I think the default value of the Mongoose schema is not reflected here because we are using the Mongo method directly?

Comment: That may be it - using direct driver methods will bypass all of Mongoose such as validation, getters, setters, etc.. The thing that I would ask myself though is why you have essentially an optional required field. You may want to remove that required call and handle it in an other way. You could write a validation function that can check for existence based on say a flag that you set somewhere (i.e. is it a csv upload). http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: It would be **required** in the other side, e.g., product creation, but it **may be optional** in this CSV import.

Comment: Then I would explore handling this in a mongoose validation function.

Comment: However, I think **optional/required** is not a case since we are using the driver method directly. If a field is not provided in the  data, it should be skip (like the insert query execute in relational database).

Comment: Well yes - what I am suggesting is either use the driver method and deal with lack of mongoose features or make a validator. One or the other.

Answer (score 55):

This is supported [since v4.4.2](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/2c887ac5bb2eee08aaf8590599075c5d86ae5fe6/test/document.test.js#L456-L467):

```
doc.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple models that use the same collection, so create a second model without the required field constraints for use with CSV import:

```
var rawProduct = mongoose.model("RawProduct", Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number
}), 'products');
```

The third parameter to `model` provides an explicit collection name, allowing you to have this model also use the `products` collection.

Comment: Well, your answer is quite considerable, but according to our application structure, schema are defined in one place. So, this could lead to the duplicate schema definition.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to ignore validation and preserve the middleware behavior by replacing the `validate` method:

```
schema.method('saveWithoutValidation', function(next) {
    var defaultValidate = this.validate;
    this.validate = function(next) {next();};

    var self = this;
    this.save(function(err, doc, numberAffected) {
        self.validate = defaultValidate;
        next(err, doc, numberAffected);
    });
});
```

I've tested it only with mongoose 3.8.23

Answer (score 2):

1. schema config validateBeforeSave=false
2. use validate methed

```js
// define

var GiftSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    image: {type: String}
},{validateBeforeSave:false});



// use 
var it new Gift({...});
it.validate(function(err){
        if (err) next(err)
        else it.save(function (err, model) {
            ...
        });
    })
```